# How to link MKUserTrackingButton to the SwiftUI map view

Tags: swiftui

In my project I am using SwiftUI:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
```

I added a MKUserTrackingButton:

```
struct UserTrackingButton: UIViewRepresentable {
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKUserTrackingButton {
   MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: context.environment.mkMapView)
}

func updateUIView(_ view: MKUserTrackingButton, context: Context) { }
```

}

But it's not working. So how can I link my SwiftUI Map view to this button?

Answer (score 3):

In the method where you create your MapView, create the MKUserTrackingButton using mapview as the reference then add the button as a subview to the map view. So something like this:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
  let mapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

  mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

  // set mapView properties as you need them

  let trackingButton = MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: mapView) 
  mapView.addSubview(trackingButton)

  // positioning the button on the right size with a bit
  // of autolayout constraints.  Adjust constants to 
  // your liking.
  trackingButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  trackingButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
  trackingButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 42).isActive = true

  return mapView
}
```

I used auto layout constraints to position the button, depending on what else you may have going on on the map you may need to adjust these and/or set the button's x, y, width, height properties.

**EDIT: June 8, 2022**

The above is a very unsatisfying answer, in part because the trackingButton object being a subview of mkmapview does not play nice with SwifUI’s layout mechanism (doesn’t play with SWIFTUI at all actually). A better way around this, though still feeling much too hacky, is going through the MapView’s model class. So here a brief layout of code that adds a MapType button. A standard map type button (such as the tracking button) does not exist so this is a more generic way to also provide a tracking button.

The MapTypeButton is a simple UIButton dedicated to cycle through the MKMapType enum choices with your choice of images in the button. Since both MKMapView and UIButton are not part of the SWIFTUI component set, they first need to be wrapped in a UIViewRepresentable. This takes the familiar form of:

```
Struct abcView:UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> abcView {
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: abcView, context: Context)
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject {
    init(_ parent: abcView) {
      self.parent = parent
      super.init()
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
      Coordinator(self)
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously replacing “abcView” with your class’ name.   The skeleton versions for MKMapView and the MapType targeting UIButton resulting in MapView and MapTypeButtonView are given below along with their model classes.

```
struct MapView : UIViewRepresentable {
  var mapViewModel:MapViewModel
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    
    let mkMapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    
    mkMapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    // any mkMapView set up stuff goes here
    mkMapView.region = mapViewModel.region
    mkMapView.showsCompass = false
    
    mapViewModel.mkMapView = mkMapView. // <— forms the bridge to MapTypeButtonView
    return mkMapView
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
  }
  
  class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var parent: MapView
    
    init(_ parent: MapView) {
      self.parent = parent
      super.init()
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    }
  }
  
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }
}




struct MapTypeButtonView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var mkMapView:MKMapView?
  
  func makeUIView(context:Context) -> MapTypeButton {
    let button = MapTypeButton()
    return button
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: MapTypeButton, context: Context) {
    uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    uiView.mkMapView = mkMapView. // <— makes MKMapView available to the button
  }
  
  class Coordinator : NSObject {
    var parent : MapTypeButtonView
    
    init (_ parent:MapTypeButtonView) {
      self.parent = parent
      super.init()
    }
  }
  
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }
}


final class MapViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  let startLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7128, longitude: -74.0060)
  let defaultSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
  @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: startLocation, span: defaultSpan)
  
  @Published var mkMapView:MKMapView?
  
  @discardableResult
  func checkIfLocationServicesEnabled() -> Bool {    // <— customize this to your liking
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      locationMgr = CLLocationManager()
      if locationMgr == nil { return false }
      locationMgr!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      locationMgr!.delegate = self
      locationMgr!.requestLocation()
      locationMgr!.startUpdatingLocation()
      locationMgr!.startUpdatingHeading()
      
      return true
    }
    else {
      // show alert ?
      return false
    }
  }
  
  private func checkLocationMgrAuthorization() {
    guard let mgr = locationMgr else { return }
    
    switch mgr.authorizationStatus {
    case .notDetermined: mgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .restricted: print("ALERT: LOCMGR RESTRICTED")
    case .denied: print("ALERT: LOCMGR DENIED")
    case .authorizedAlways:
      region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mgr.location!.coordinate, span: self.defaultSpan)
      
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
      // Info.plist must contain both “NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription”
      // and “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription”
      mgr.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      
    @unknown default:
      break
    }
  }
  
  
  func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
    checkLocationMgrAuthorization()
  }
  
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    //
  }
  
}
```

I set up the MapType button so that it cycles through the .standard and .hybrid map types only, call nextMapType() to cycle through. Change to your liking.

```
class MapTypeButton : UIView {
  let buttonWidthHeight = 32
  weak open var mkMapView: MKMapView?
  private var mapTypes:[MKMapType] = [.standard, .hybrid]
  private var mapTypeImageNames:[String] = [“map”, "map.fill"]
  private var button:UIButton?
  
  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: buttonWidthHeight, height: buttonWidthHeight)
  }
  
  var mapType : MKMapType {
    get { return mkMapView?.mapType ?? .standard }
    set { mkMapView?.mapType = newValue }
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }
  
  init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonWidthHeight, height: buttonWidthHeight))
    self.setup()
  }
  
  private func setup() {
    let action = UIAction(image: UIImage(systemName: mapTypeImageNames[0]),
                          handler: { _ in self.nextMapType() })
    self.button = UIButton(primaryAction: action)
    
    if let btn = self.button {
      self.addSubview(btn)
      
      btn.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
      btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
      
      btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      _ = btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
      _ = btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
      _ = btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
      _ = btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
  }
  
  func nextMapType() {
    guard let mapView = self.mkMapView else { return }
    if let idx = self.mapTypes.firstIndex(of: mapView.mapType) {
      var i = mapTypes.distance(from: mapTypes.startIndex, to: idx)
      i += 1
      i = i % self.mapTypes.count
      mapView.mapType = mapTypes[i]
      self.button?.setImage(UIImage(systemName: mapTypeImageNames[i]), for:.normal)
      self.button?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
      self.button?.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, to put it all together in a content view whereby the map is in the background and the MapTypeButton on top (along with some other button for show and tell) floats in the center horizontally);

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var mapViewModel = MapViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      MapView(mapViewModel: mapViewModel)
      HStack {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "heart.fill") }
        Spacer()
        MapTypeButtonView(mkMapView: $mapViewModel.mkMapView)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can now create a similar set up for a TrackingButton (I would not use MKTrackingButton). The MapTypeButtonView should play well within SWIFTUI and follow all expected layout requirements, yet has a direct connection to the MKMapView to control it.

Right, a ton of code, most of which is needed for other purposes also so therefore not entirely out of the blue but still a bit more cumbersome than it should be perhaps. Hopefully it helps you or anybody else.

Comment: Hello, Yohst, thanks a lot for your answer!
Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104303/how-to-create-a-draggable-annotation-using-swiftui-map.  ?